# Why does CMD never work in my Dockerfiles?

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I have a few Dockerfiles where CMD doesn't seem to run.  Here is an example (all the way at the bottom).

```
##########################################################
# Set the base image to Ansible
FROM ubuntu:16.10

# Install Ansible, Python and Related Deps #
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y python-yaml python-jinja2 python-httplib2 python-keyczar python-paramiko python-setuptools python-pkg-resources git python-pip
RUN mkdir /etc/ansible/
RUN echo '[local]\nlocalhost\n' > /etc/ansible/hosts
RUN mkdir /opt/ansible/
RUN git clone http://github.com/ansible/ansible.git /opt/ansible/ansible
WORKDIR /opt/ansible/ansible
RUN git submodule update --init
ENV PATH /opt/ansible/ansible/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
ENV PYTHONPATH /opt/ansible/ansible/lib
ENV ANSIBLE_LIBRARY /opt/ansible/ansible/library
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python -y
RUN apt-get install python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install python-setuptools -y
RUN apt-get install python-pip

RUN mkdir /ansible/
WORKDIR /ansible
COPY ./ansible ./
WORKDIR /

RUN ansible-playbook -c local ansible/playbooks/installdjango.yml

ENV PROJECTNAME testwebsite

################## SETUP DIRECTORY STRUCTURE ######################

WORKDIR /home

CMD ["django-admin" "startproject" "$PROJECTNAME"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

If I build and run the container, I can manually run 
Django-admin startproject $PROJECTNAME and it will create a new project as expected, but the CMD in my Dockerfile does not seem to be doing anything and this is happening with all my other Dockerfiles so there's something I must not be getting.

Comment: Try to Use comma separator between CMD input: CMD ["django-admin", "startproject", "$PROJECTNAME"], or check docker logs containerid

Comment: Okay I just tried but still same issue.

Comment: What is docker logs output? And what does "I can manually run Django-admin startproject $PROJECTNAME" mean - How do you run this command?

Comment: I run my container docker run -I -t <containerid> /bin/bash  and then from shell I type django-admin startproject $PROJECTNAME

Comment: there is nothing in my docker log

Comment: I am running docker logs -f  <containerid>

Comment: How are you running the container normally? (not with the -it flag) ?

Comment: the way I posted above, is how I always run the container

Comment: Did you try ´CMD [ "django-admin", "startproject hello_world_django" ]´ ? [like here](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-django-application)

Comment: What do you mean 'the way you posted above'. If you run it with `-it` every time then your command is never going to run, as you're overwriting it with `/bin/bash` everytime you run the container.

Comment: Vlad I tried this command, and still same issue.  John I'm not sure what you mean.  I always run with -i -t

Comment: See @BMitch answer (which is basically a longer version of my comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` defines the default command that docker runs when it starts your container, not when the image is built. When `ENTRYPOINT` isn't defined, you simply run the value of `CMD`. Otherwise, `CMD` becomes args to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  When you run your image, you can override the value of the `CMD` by passing args after the container name.

So, in your example above, `CMD` may be defined as anything, but when you run your container with `docker run -it <imagename> /bin/bash`, you override any value of `CMD` and replace it with /bin/bash. To run the defined value of `CMD`, you would need to run the container with `docker run <imagename>`.